# First steps to reconstruct the architecture in a Delphi 7 project

Tags: delphi, architecture, delphi-7

I am working with an undocumented, 100.000 lines Delphi 7 project and one of my goals is to create a software architecture document from the source code.

Can you give me any ideas on how to approach this?

Comment: What are your intentions with the code? If you have to start maintaining it, just start, and in the proces document what you come across. This is the fastest way to get up to steam, you have the editor and debugger to help you point out dependencies follow program flow. I've done that for a large project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These tools work with Delphi 7 and are of great help:

- the UML tool [ModelMaker](http://www.modelmakertools.com/modelmaker/index.html)
- the refacotoring tool [ModelMaker Code Explorer](http://www.modelmakertools.com/code-explorer/index.html)
- the documentation tool [Documentation Insight](http://www.devjetsoftware.com/products/documentation-insight/) ([as of august 2012](http://www.devjetsoftware.com/products/documentation-insight/documentation-insight-update-v2-6-8-20/))

UML diagrams are a great way to get an overview of structure. How well that overview is, depends on how well the structure is.

For taking over projects like these, I start with some basic documentation (often in [MarkDown format](http://lifehacker.com/5943320/what-is-markdown-and-why-is-it-better-for-my-to+do-lists-and-notes), as that text based format is version control friendly, and generates nice HTML).

To get that going, it helps if the original developers or/and some base documentation are still there.

Then just start to:

- fix bugs / apply feature requests
- use ModelMaker to get a feel for overall structure
- use ModelMaker Code Explorer as a refactoring tool
- use Documentation Insight to document inside the source code (you can generate help files and web pages with the pro version, see [feature matrix](http://www.devjetsoftware.com/products/documentation-insight/feature-matrix/))
- update my Markdown documents with any information that does not fit in the source code documentation well

Note you can put some documentation in using Model Maker Code Explorer, but it can not be exported as help files, since it uses a different documentation format than Documentation Insight.

So I agree with the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18243145/first-steps-to-reconstruct-the-architecture-in-a-delphi-7-project/18250685#comment26757588_18243145) by [Jan Doggen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/512728/jan-doggen) (thanks Jan!): just start. Make sure you have the right tools to help that going.

Answer (score 2):

Try running the source code through a newer Delphi version that supports UML modeling, then let it show you how different sections of code related to each other.

Answer (score 1):

**[Understand](http://www.scitools.com)** will do the job. Free download includes 15 days evaluation which will be more then enough for what you need to document.

Comment: Being curious: Is there any public pricing on that? And: does it, next to [support for Borland Delphi Language](https://www.scitools.com/features/metrics.php), also support the additions that Embarcadero made?